# Chrome Debugger skip wrapper functions, until they call the real function

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, debugger

I am debugging in Chrome, there are some functions that are just wrappers, and I want to quickly skip them, something like this:

```
function breakpointHere() {
  step1();
  callWrappedFunc();
}

function callWrappedFunc() {
  blablabla();
  callRealFunc();
}

function callRealFunc() {
  ohYeah();
}
```

Here `callWrappedFunc` has no important value, I want to completely skip and jump right into `callRealFunc`, how do I do that?

Comment: Hvae you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827882/avoid-stepping-through-javascript-file-in-chrome-developer-tools this?

Comment: @malakrsnaslava, It definitely helps, and probably solves my issue, though it skips the whole file, I will accept an answer that skips a single function.